# Apache mod_rewrite to lighttpd

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I'm trying to transfer a PHP project from apache to lighttpd. I have the following rewrite in the apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I can't manage to translate it to lighttpd mod_rewrite.

Here are some of my attempts:

```
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        # try with two separate matches - when the request ends with file.ext
        "\.(?!(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf))[\?]{0,1}(.*)$" => "/index.php?_url=/$1",
        # if the request ends with /
        "/[\?]{0,1}$" => "/index.php?_url=/"

#        ".+/(.*)?(.*)" => "/index.php?_url=/$1",

#         "((?!\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf)).*)" => "/index.php?_url=/$1"

#        "^([^\?(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf)]+)[\?]{0,1}(.*)$" => "/index.php?_url=$1&$2"
    )
```

With the last version the only difference I see the only difference in PHP's $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']. It is:
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /v1/en/entity/method/  # with the apache
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php  # with the lighttpd

The request itself is:
https://api.local/v1/en/entity/method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.example.com" {
    # rewrite the url if there is no such file and not a listed extension
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "\.(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf)$" => "",
        ".*" => "/index.php?_url=$0"
    )
}
```

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must place this code in `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-rewrite.conf` after 
`server.modules += ("mod_rewrite")` 
or in the `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/90-vhosts.conf` at the corresponding vhost (respectively in the conf-available and point a symlink to conf-enabled)

you cannot place it in .htaccess

BUT OK lets admit this is the domain www.example.com

```
http['HOST'] == "www.example.com"{
    // rewrite the url if there is no such file and
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^(.*)!\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf)$" => "/index.php?_url=/$1"
    )
}
```

this should work the same way as in Apache.
(I haven't tested it)

Comment: All the config files are OK and the configuration is placed where it should be.

Comment: This doesn't work, in apache ! means negate, while here you are using it as normal character. I tried your code with negative lookahead:
```"^(.*)(?!\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|ttf))$" => "/index.php?_url=/$1"``` but it doesn't work either.

All the config files are OK and the configuration is placed where it should be.
I'm using evhost if it matters.